# Duplicate lexical declaration; cannot redefine let or const variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, ecmascript-6

I am using VS 2015 Community for a Node application using [nodejstools](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools#readme) tool.

Using the following code I get an error in "Error List" palette. Despite this, the application runs fine.

I am wondering why this error happens in my code or it is a bug related to VS IDE.

```
'use strict';

const Q = require('q')
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
const fs = require('fs');
const del = require('del');
const removeDirectories = require('remove-empty-directories');
```

Edit:

[Source code for this exception](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/blob/master/Nodejs/Product/Analysis/JavaScript/activationobject.cs).

[Bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejstools/issues/862)

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, nothing wrong with that code. Doesn't happen in my VS2015 Ultimate though

Comment: I think the same. I have notice the problem is on VS 2015 Community and using NTVS V1.1. After updating to Node.js Tools 1.2 Alpha no errors and its fine. I will report to MS team. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Was about a bug in software. No longer a bug, question needs no answer and should be removed.